# Couldn't find cython libraries

Tags: python, cython

I found the following problem in executing my python function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ppd/myfunc.py", line 2, in <module>
    from   cythonUtilsPy.cythonUtils import *
ImportError: No module named cythonUtils
```

How to add this `cythonUtils` module to my path?

Comment: I don't recognize `cythonUtilsPy.cythonUtils` -- that's a very strange name convention (in Python) and not one I think that a typical Python programmer would use.  Google returns zero results for me for `cythonUtilsPy`.  There *is* a Cython Utils module (Cython.Utils); is `cythonUtilsPy.cythonUtils` meant to be some wrapper for it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, it looks like `cythonUtilsPy` is already on your path and was found, but the submodule `cythonUtilsPy.cythonUtils` was not found.  Unless you are importing the wrong `cythonUtilsPy`, there is no path manipulation you can do to fix this.

You need to track down why `cythonUtils` is not showing up as a submodule of `cythonUtilsPy`, if `cythonUtils` is a directory perhaps it is missing an `__init__.py`.